# Compare two strings by ignoring certain substrings

Tags: c#

I am developing a comparison tool to compare two lines which are text strings.The condition is that,i will need to take a certain part of the substring and ignore it for comparison.So for e.g.

two lines

FILE = .test\testfile CRC = 0x0987678 DATE = 10/09/2015 VERSION = 1

File = .test\testfile CRC = 0x0984567 DATE = 11/09/2015 VERSION = 1

if two filters are provided as CRC and DATE,then i need to ignore the complete field and value.so CRC = 0x0987678 DATE = 10/09/2015 will be ignored for comparison and only rest of the string will be compared and in above case will return true,as the rest of the string is same.

Now i can do this by searching string,removing white spaces,getting the value etc but i am looking for a solution with regular expressions to optimize my solutions.Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any regular expressions yet? If so, what have you tried?

Comment: I would suggest to either use some pre-processing of the data to obtain a 'normalized' representation of the strings, which is generated by removing the irrelevant parts, or to write a comparison function which does this on-the-fly. What makes you think that regular expressions do this in a better way?

Comment: I have not yet tried regex but just thought it would make for a better approach,as i have not explored the potential of this utility in c#.Will try things out,but any suggestions are welcome,which include not using  regex and going with the conventional approach.

Comment: Ok,I just want to know,if there is a string like:"File = .test\testfile CRC = 0x0984567 DATE = 11/09/2015 VERSION = 1" and want to compare it with another string by ignoring certain parts of the strings,is there an efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this question.  First to get the parameters.  Second to do the filtering.  Regex is the best solution to the first part.  The filtering can be done lots of different ways.  Here is the regex part.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "FILE = .test\testfile CRC = 0x0987678 DATE = 10/09/2015 VERSION = 1";
            string pattern = @"(?'name'[\w]+)\s+=\s+(?'value'[^\s]+)";

            Regex expr = new Regex(pattern);
            MatchCollection matches = expr.Matches(input);

            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            foreach (Match match in matches)
            {
                dict.Add(match.Groups["name"].Value, match.Groups["value"].Value);
            }
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: Works fine to split,but there will be cases in the strings which would be like:
END FILE and XYZ FILE = ".....".

Can we modify the regex pattern?e.g. 

TW FILES

    XYZ FILE = "/test/test files" VERSION = 1 CRC = 0xFFFFFFFF

 END TW FILES

Comment: The pattern looks for only the word before and after then equal sign and ignores everything else.

Comment: Ok,I just want to know,if there is a string like:"File = .test\testfile CRC = 0x0984567 DATE = 11/09/2015 VERSION = 1" and want to compare it with another string by ignoring certain parts of the strings,is there an efficient way to do it?

Comment: The two string could have different spacing and different ordering,  One could be missing a fragment.  The best way is like what I did is to put one in a dictionary and then compare each fragment of second against first.

Comment: Just thinking, you can join the two string by the name of each fragment using Linq Outer Join.  See following webpage : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b  An outer join will give nulls where second string is missing items that isn't in first string.  A regular join will only give all items in first string and items in second string that matches (doesn't give the non matching items).